Chrome extension manifest v3 why sometimes the tab has no ID?
Here is my code.
chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener(   async (request: any, _sender: any, _sendResponse: any) => { if (request.message === 'getGlobalTabID') {             _sendResponse({globalTabID: ServiceWorkerGlobals.globalTabID, currentTabID: _sender.tab.id});       }   }, );`

I'm getting error in Production which is that sometimes the _sender.tab has no id, now I'm trying to look through documentation but could not find any clue why this can be the case.
getGlobalTabID is sent from content-script.js which runs on all https sites.
chrome.runtime.sendMessage({message: 'getGlobalTabID'}, async response => { })`

Any clue to identify why content script is even ran on a tab that has no ID?
Ideally, every tab should have ID in this scenario since the content script do not run on dev tool windows that has no tab ID.

The documentation lists some of these cases (link), but there may be more, theoretically. It may be also a bug in Chrome. BTW async listener for onMessage is not supported by the API, more info.

@woxxom Thanks for the async, I really thought its in use, will remove that.
Also, I tested the listed cases like by first removing the tabs, then restoring it but still the error isn't thrown. On devtool windows, which I tried to open in separate tab but I still didn't' see the error neither content script running on it.
Do you think it can be anything else? The code is pretty straightforward, I see the errors in production so shall I add more logging or do a check before sending tab ID to resolve this issue?
